# curl chunky parser error

Tags: linux, curl

"Received problem 3 in the chunky parser"

I can't for the life of me find what "problem 3" in curl refers to. I'm sure it has to do with the format of the chunk I'm sending from the app server to curl, but I can't figure out what is wrong with the chunk because I can't tell what "problem 3" is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some more details would be a good idea if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

The number you see there is CHUNKE_BAD_CHUNK from the CHUNKcode enum from [lib/http_chunks.h](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/http_chunks.h) from the libcurl source code. Given a quick look, it seems that it is mostly used when a CR or LF is missing from the chunked data.

I would recommend you investigate on the raw HTTP content stream to see what the problem is with the chunked format. [RFC2616 section 3.6.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html) documents it.

Comment: I eventually tracked it down by reading the Wikipedia article on chunked encoding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), some trial and error, and Wireshark. The problem turned out to be that I was using the length of my string, but the response buffer that was actually written was larger than the original string so it included several octets of nulls, resulting in my count and the actual octets being different.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar post to yours. Again I'm not sure what your trying to sen across so I can not point out the problem but have look at this,

> [Why is this warning being shown: "Received problem 2 in the chunky parser"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392041/why-is-this-warning-being-shown-received-problem-2-in-the-chunky-parser)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So, I ran into this with a CGI program.

Long story short, the CGI script was using Python, and printing the chunk header using the length of the string, then sending to the client using:

```
print data,
```

This appends a space, making the data one byte longer than the chunk header says it is.  I fixed this by changing that line to:

```
stdout.write( data )
```

A hexdump of the data out of the CGI script was the tool that finally told me what was going on.